# Как при распространение программы (exe), оставить файл txt с которого копируются данные

Tags: c++, c

Допустим есть программа на C++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <String>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    ifstream fin("input.txt");
    string s;
    getline(fin, s);
    cout << "Hello" << s;
    return 0;
}
```

Есть файл input.txt в нем имя, как этот txt файл сохранить когда буду передавать программу(сохранить нужно для того что будет в файле строк 200 текста, и данные файла будут использоваться)

Comment: Очевидно, передать txt файл вместе с программой

Comment: Можно просто вогнать в exe как ресурс, например... Если это для Win, а файл неизменный. Но 200 строк — это нынче так немного, что можно и в программу прошить :)

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Можно тупо присоединить файл в конец экзешника (это легко автоматизировать с помощью bat/cmd), а в коде программы написать, чтобы она открывала сама себя и читала присоединённые данные с конца.

Comment: @Harry а прошить программу это про что?

Comment: Прошить в программе. Написать что-то типа `char input[] = ` и текст вашего файла. И вместо чтения из файла работать с его содержимым, как уже считанным в память. Еще раз, если файл не изменяется от вызова к вызову...